# Can we publish a web application running on a different server in WSO2 APP Manager 1.0.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am publishing a web application in WSO2 APP manager 1.0.0.After subscription, I am able to land on the login page of the application but once providing the credentials, blank page is seen.I would like to know if there are any configurations needed in the wso2 app manager for the server in which web app is running for invoking the web app properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you were able to land on the 'login page' do you mean the login page of App Manager Login or the log in page of the Web App?

What are the errors/exceptions logged on the console?

If it is the App Manager log in page this could be related to incorrect service provider details recorded against the web application *(Eg: incorrect Assertion Consumer URLs etc*).

If you are referring to the Application's log in page, this could happen due to the  App being secured with username/password.

When an App is secured, App Manager needs to send a JWT token as a HTTP header to the back-end Application once the user is authenticated.
In this case a few changes are required to be made in the App itself to support this.
The App should be modified to read the JWT token and identify the user and skip giving the login page.
The document [1] explains this in detail.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/APPM100/Securing+Web+Applications+Using+JWT